# Is there a way to fix blurry text in Chrome 88?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

See JS Fiddle in Chrome Browser, version 88.
https://jsfiddle.net/3qr8h6tx/3/

When I have the following CSS:

```css
div {
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
```

When I change the transform property of the element, the text inside the element gets blurred.

In Chrome Beta (version 89) and Chrome Canary (version 90), this issue doesn't exist.

Is there a way to fix the blurry text on Chrome version 88?

Comment: try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth), but please take care of the notes in it.

Comment: It seems like the issue is fixed in Chrome Browser, version 89. ‍♂️